# what different between fflush(FILE* stream) and fflush(NULL) at c?

Tags: c, file, buffer, fflush

what different between fflush(FILE* stream) and fflush(NULL) at c?
I know that fflush(NULL) flush all the stream
what is fflush(FILE* stream) do?

Comment: One of its uses: `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Flush one specific stream, or flush all output streams. See e.g. [this `fflush` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush)

Comment: If you know that `fflush(NULL)` flushes all the streams then how come you don't know that `fflush(FILE* stream)` flushes the given stream?

Comment: `fflush(FILE* stream)` forward declares `fflush` as a function accepting a `FILE*`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the details from “man fflush”(“fflush() forces a write of all user-space buffered data for the given output or update stream via the stream's underlying write function ”from man )